# Liquid Error: Array 'collection.products' is not paginateable

Tags: shopify, liquid

i have created a component in section and write name bottom.liquid and copied code from collection-template both have same schema and created in section folder but i am only getting error in bottom.liquid[image]

and here is my bottom.liquid code

```
{% paginate collection.products by 12 %}
  
  {% assign productCount = collection.all_products_count | minus: paginate.current_offset %}

  <div class=" container-fluid  lemon-con ">
        
        <div class="column-title">
          <h3 class="h3 main-lemo-heading text-center">
            DIRTYLEMON
        </h3>
        </div>
      
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md">
                {% if section.settings.collection_nav %}

                  {% assign sidebarNav = section.settings.collection_nav %}

                  <div class="list-card mb-4">
                      <div class="card-header product-hidden">
                        <strong>{{ linklists[sidebarNav].title }}</strong>
                      </div>
                      <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                        
                          {% for link in linklists[sidebarNav].links %}
                             <li class="list-group-itm">
                               <a  href="{{ link.url }}">{{ link.title }}</a>

                             </li>
                          {% endfor %}
                      </ul>
                      

                  </div>
                  
                {% endif %}

                {% if collection.all_tags.size > 0 and section.settings.hide_tags != true %}
                  <div class="list-card mb-4">
                      <div>
                        <strong>Tags</strong>
                      </div>

                      <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                        {% for tag in collection.all_tags %}
                          {% if current_tags contains tag %}
                            <li class="list-group-itm bg-primary">
                              {{ tag | link_to_remove_tag: tag }}
                            </li>
                          {% else %}
                            <li class="list-group-itm side-bar">
                              {{ tag | link_to_tag: tag }}
                            </li>
                          {% endif %}
                        {% endfor %}
                      </ul>

                  </div>
                {% endif %}

            </div>

      

        </div>



  </div>

  
{% endpaginate %}



{% schema %}
  {
    "name": "bottom",
    "settings": [
      {
        "type": "header",
        "content": "Collection header"
      },
      {
        "type": "text",
        "id": "title",
        "label": "Heading",
        "default": "slider title"
    },
      {
        "type": "checkbox",
        "id": "is_full_width",
        "label": "Full width",
        "default": false
      },
      {
        "type": "select",
        "id": "header_align",
        "options": [
            { 
              "value": "right", 
              "label": "Text right"
            },
            { 
              "value": "center", 
              "label": "Text center"
            },
            { 
              "value": "left", 
              "label": "Text left"
            }
        ],
        "label": "Header alignment",
        "default": "left"
      },
      {
        "type":      "range",
        "id":        "header_height",
        "min":       50,
        "max":        500,
        "step":       5,
        "unit":       "px",
        "label":     "Header height",
        "default":   120
      },
      {
        "type": "header",
        "content": "Sidebar"
      },
      {
        "type": "link_list",
        "id": "collection_nav",
        "label": "Navigation",
        "info": "Select custom menu nav for sidebar"
      },
      {
        "type": "checkbox",
        "id": "hide_tags",
        "label": "Hide tags",
        "default": false,
        "info": "Hide tags from sidebar"
      },
      {
        "type": "header",
        "content": "Others"
      },
      {
        "type": "paragraph",
        "content": "You can add more settings here :) "
      }
    ],
    "presets": [
        {
            "name": "bottom",
            "category": "Image"
        }
    ]
  
  }
{% endschema %}
```

both have same code but I am getting error in bottom.liquid in bottom.liquid i have copied same code on above image collection.template but i am only facing error in bottom.liquid
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For why it is not working, the Shopify Docs for [Global objects](https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/liquid/reference/objects) does not mention collection as a global object. So your code only works on Collection pages where **collection** object in Liquid refers to collection being viewed.

So what you can do is, use collections global object and then paginate the required collection using collection handle.

```
{% paginate collections['my-handle'].products by 12 %}
{% endpaginate %}
```

If you want to select Collection using theme Customizer, you can use setting type of [Collection](https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/settings#collection).

```
{
   "type": "collection",
   "id": "feature_collection",
   "label": "Feature collection"
}
```

Comment: bilal i am new to shopify and I facing a lot of difficulties

Comment: can you please guide